# VSS migration to TFS - folder structure change caused project mismappings

Tags: migration, visual-sourcesafe

A company did a VSS6 to TFS2010 migration, but the folder structure was changed during the migration (I don't think any tools were used). Due to the folder structure change, the relative project paths in solution files are invalid so none of the 50+ applications work !

My task is to fix it up. **I'm looking for advice to help me scan through the solution files in VSS getting absolute project paths and then doing the same in TFS in order to re-ma all the projects to match the new folder structure in TFS.**

I cant redo the migration either as development has continued by developers in a foreign country (they've taken PROD DLLs to get the solutions working with invalid projects ref's).

I've done research but cant find any tools and dont really want to have to write a utility to do it, eg
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.projectitem.aspx

Comment: A judicious `search & replace` with a decent grep tool would go a long way. fwiw, we are in the process of migrating from VSS6 to TFS ourselves and I am changing our Delphi projects using a mix of Powergrep and Vim.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. After a good think over the weekend I'm going to do a Folder WinDiff and come up with a reference re-mapping list that way and fix the project paths in the solution files manually.