# Moving projects from VisualSourceSafe to Team Foundation Server 2013

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-sourcesafe

I am learning to use **TFS 2013** as we want to move from VSS this year.
So I created a sample project structure replica in my VSS. It looks something like below:

[image]

Now I used the [VSS Upgrade Tool for TFS](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/867f310a-db30-4228-bbad-7b9af0089282) and ported the VSS datasource to TFS MyTeamProject1. It ran fine and created the structure same as above except instead of $/ it is under MyTeamProject1.

- Each folder under the Websites folder has it's own solution.
- Each website solution has reference[Added as external project] to one or more library projects from the ClassLibraires Solution.

Now when I open the TFSWebsite1.sln in VisualStudio from TFS, it opens but could not load the libraries project. I had to manually add the library project to the solution again.

In VSS, if say another developer opens the Website solution for the first time, it would fetch all the other projects if not already found on the local machine.

**Question:** Did I miss something during upgrade or I am missing something in TFS itself?
How can I make sure that when someone grabs the solution for the first time, the corresponding projects are brought along by TFS?

Comment: Here is another post on the issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7763716/vss-migration-to-tfs-folder-structure-change-caused-project-mismappings
Not sure if there is a better way to solve the problem.

Comment: I'd wager it's because you needed to update the source control bindings to point to TFS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In TFS, I had to manually map the client libraries and websites to the local workspace and get the latest version for each of them.

I also had to manually update the project references, build the class libraries first and then build the website.

In any case, got it working somehow.